# Upload Backend Server to Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, backend

I am doing Google Cloud Platform Sample Application, by following this [Smashpix application Link from github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-orchestrator-android-sampleapp-smashpix)

This link providing a android application that upload an image and it will autoscale the image.

In that procedure, In the BackEnd Configuration part, I created Web Client ID, Service Account, Installed Application ID and Buckets for storing the image. But there is a line,which indicated upload the back end server to the google app engine.

- Extract the Google Cloud Storage App Engine client dependency,
  src/cloudstorage/, folder into your backend server directory,
  [BACKEND_SERVER_CODE]/cloudstorage/ In the app.yaml file, replace
  [APPENGINE_ID] with your App Engine application ID application:
  [APPENGINE_ID]
- In the queue.yaml file, replace [SERVICE_ACCOUNT] with
  the email address of the Service account queue:
  name: imagetasks   ...   acl: [SERVICE_ACCOUNT]
- In the settings.cfg file, replace the variable placeholders with your application variables
- MAIN_BUCKET: Primary Google Cloud Storage bucket to upload
  original images  BIT_BUCKET: Google Cloud Storage bucket to store
  processed images  APP_HOSTNAME: Full App Engine hostname, 
  [APPENGINE_ID].appspot.com
- **Upload the backend server to Google App Engine**

After Some googled,
There is a line `appcfg backends <dir> update backend_name`.

What can i proceed now, Please Give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It just means upload your app. In the folder for the backend run

```
appcfg.py update .
```

Don't forget the period.